# How to reduce the processor speed and memory size?

Tags: reduce, low-memory

I want to simulate resource constraint devices with low processing power like 20 MHz and low memory like 128 KB Flash, 32 KB RAM. I want to execute certain C program to check their running time on such conditions. How can I go about accomplishing this?

On simulIDE, I use a microprocessor and was trying to run C program with pairing based cryptography (PBC) library to check the running time of various operations like pairing, point multiplication etc. But I couldn't linked the PBC library. So I am wondering if there is any way where I can simulate a resource constraint conditions and run my program.

Comment: Use a virtual machine and use the limitations that are configurable for that VM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that you will be linking your cryptography library on every machine to which you plan to deploy.

Do your compiling, linking and installation on a virtual machine that has ample memory and other resources. Run some tests to establish "baseline behaviour" when there's ample memory.

Once you have confirmed that the test binary is running successfully, either alter the virtual machine's configuration to have less memory or copy the binary to a virtual machine with less memory. Then compare the behaviour with low memory with the "baseline behaviour".